# SQL GROUP BY - Multiple results in one column?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to perform a SELECT query using a GROUP BY clause, however I also need to access data from multiple rows and somehow concatenate it into a single column.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
COUNT(v.id) AS quantity, 
vt.name AS name, 
vt.cost AS cost, 
vt.postage_cost AS postage_cost 
FROM vouchers v 
INNER JOIN voucher_types vt 
ON v.type_id = vt.id 
WHERE 
v.order_id = 1 AND 
v.sold = 1 
GROUP BY vt.id
```

Which gives me the first four columns I need in the following format.

```
quantity | name | cost | postage_cost
2           X      5         1
2           Y      6         1
```

However, I would also like a fifth column to be displayed, showing all of the codes associated with each line of the order like this:

```
code
ABCD, EFGH
IJKL, MNOP
```

Where the comma separated values are pulled from the voucher table.

Is this possible?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) does.

Assuming the column is called `code` you would just add `,GROUP_CONCAT(v.code) As Codes` to your `select` list.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never heard of that before